# Typescript Generation explicitly adds inherited properties to inheriting class after updating to 8.1.2

Tags: servicestack

I updated ServiceStack in a project from 8.0.0 to 8.1.2 yesterday. Before updating the Typescript generated by the NativeTypesService would look like this:

```js
interface InheritedType {
  propertyName: string;
}

interface OtherType : InheritedType {}
```

But after updating this is produced:

```js
interface InheritedType {
  propertyName: string;
}

interface OtherType : InheritedType {
  propertyName: string;
}
```

Is there some setting that has been added/changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should now be resolved in the latest ServiceStack v8.1.3+ that's now available in [Pre Release packages](https://docs.servicestack.net/pre-release).